# Add a button to the right of tabpane

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have a tabpane with some tabs. I want to add a single button on the same line as the tabs (should be right aligned and opposite to the tabs).

I was thinking I can add the Button like: (but this doesnt work)

`tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1,tab2,tab3,new Button("btn"))`

Please tell me how to do this (see example of image of what i want below).

[image]

NOTE: THE BUTTON SHOULD ONLY BE VISIBLE WHEN TAB1 OF THE TABAREA IS ACTIVE. THE BUTTON SHOULD BE HIDDEN WHEN ON TAB2 AND TAB3. THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane` you can group your tabpages and button into same layout

Refer code below,

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXTest6 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        final TabPane tabs = new TabPane();
        final Button addButton = new Button("Btn1");
        addButton.setPrefWidth(41);
        addButton.setPrefHeight(15);

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tabs, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tabs, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tabs, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(addButton, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(addButton, 10.0);
        tabs.setStyle("-fx-padding: 2 0 0 50;");

        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab 1");
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 3");

        tabs.getTabs().add(tab);
        tabs.getTabs().add(tab1);
        tabs.getTabs().add(tab2);

        root.getChildren().addAll(tabs, addButton);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs with button !");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> -----------------out put will be like this --------------------

[image]

Comment: sorry i did not mention that i only want "Btn1" to appear when "Tab1" is active... The button should be hidden otherwise. Can you help?

Comment: dw i fixed it.. allg g